# Hide LoginViewController or dismiss to parentView

Tags: ios, objective-c, unwind-segue

This is a normal LoginView calling on a specific action in my app

## sourceViewVontroller

```
if ([password length] == 0) {

     loginViewController *seatView = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loggingView"];



    [self presentViewController:login animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

it checks if user not signed in yet when he's calling this action, so it redirects him to the loginViewController, then

## loginViewController

```
UIStoryboard *mainStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

DestinationViewController *Dest = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destView"];


[self presentViewController:Dest animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it goes to the destinationView that needs a login, now my problem is how to go back (dismiss not presentmodalView) to the sourceViewController, or simply, how to remove the loginViewController from the queue on success and dismiss directly to the source?

## destinationViewController

```
// Tried to use presentView .. but i dont need to reload sourceView, just dismiss to it !

//[self presentViewController:srcView animated:YES completion:NULL];

//This is what am doing ..

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
```

Or just let me know if there is other professional way to do this login flow

Comment: your process is wrong

Comment: You are doing wrong implementation

Comment: Can you send me your coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `presentViewController` for bringing login controller.
Complete Process : 
In Singleton class. set a global property.

```
@property (assign)BOOL isUserLoggedIn;
```

When user logs in or logs out, set this variable to true or false.

Set an enum in LoginViewController.

```
typedef enum {

    DestViewControllerOne =1,

    DestViewControllerTwo

} SignInType;
```

In this enum, put all your view controller where you wanna put that login check.
Set a property in login view controller to hold source controller value -

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger signInType;
```

Set up a delegate in login controller to redirect after successfull login -

```
@protocol SignInProtocolDelegate <NSObject>
@optional

-(void) signInSuccess:(NSInteger) signInType;

@end
```

Create a property with that delegate in login controller -

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSObject<SignInProtocolDelegate>* delegate;
```

Now before proceeding to required view controller, perform below check -

```
if(![[TESingleton shareData] isUserLoggedIn]){

                [self funcNavigateToSignInWithAlert:YES withSignInType:proceedToDestViewControllerOne];

            }
            else
            {
                [self proceedToDestViewControllerOne];
            }

-(void)funcNavigateToSignInWithAlert:(BOOL)showAlert withSignInType:(NSInteger) signIntype
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARDNAME bundle:nil];
    LoginViewController *viewController = (LoginViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
    [viewController setSignInType:signIntype];
    [viewController setDelegate:self];
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

By this, it will bring login page.

Next - 
After successfull login, Do this in login controller :

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

[[self delegate] signInSuccess:self.signInType];
```

Import login delegate method in source controller that we have written above -

```
-(void) signInSuccess:(NSInteger) signInType
{
    switch (signInType)
    {
        case DestViewControllerOne:
            [self performSelector:@selector(proceedToDestViewControllerOne) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
            break;

        case DestViewControllerTwo:
            [self performSelector:@selector(proceedToDestViewControllerTwo) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Implement these methods in source view controller -

```
-(void) proceedToDestViewControllerOne
{
    //Restricting navigation to signin
    //Addded by vikas Jul 8,2015
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORYBOARDNAME bundle:nil];

    DestViewcontrollerOne *objDestViewcontrollerOne = (DestViewcontrollerOne *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DestViewcontrollerOne"];

    [self.navigationController objDestViewcontrollerOne animated:YES];

}
```

This is complete process.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks alot for this full answer, already tried and it WORKS !

Comment: @samir - If its working fine, then kindly vote up my answer.

Comment: Tried to do so bro, but still have no 15 reputation to vote up :S

Comment: OKieee..Got it.. Thnx @samir

Answer (score 1):

I suggest for you another way:

First in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

You will check user login or not. If login you will set `rootView` to `destinationViewController`. If not set `rootView` to `loginViewController`

SampleCode:

```
UIStoryboard *mainStory = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
if (logged) {

   DestinationViewController *Dest = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"destView"];
self.window.rootViewController = Dest;
} else {
   LoginViewController *seatView = [mainStory instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loggingView"];
   self.window.rootViewController = seatView;
}
```

When logout you just call `notification` or `delegate` set `rootViewController` of `window` to `loginViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Unwind Segues**

Add a method in `SourceViewController`

For Swift

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

For Objective-C

```
- (IBAction)unwindToThisViewController:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue {

}
```

You can come back to the `SourceViewController` in two ways.

1. Using `Storyboard` e.g when an `UIButton` action fires.
2. Using `performSegueWithIdentifier` in code.

**Storyboard:**

Control drag form an `UIButton` in `DestinationViewController` to `Exit` segue in`SourceViewController`

[image]

**In Code:**

1. Control drag form an `UIButton` in `DestinationViewController` to `Exit` segue in`SourceViewController`

[image]

2. Call `performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ExitToSourceViewController"` when need to come back to `SourceViewController`